# Which graph is correct?

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image]

By applying a rectangular signal (of 2 V amplitude) in a non inverting amplifier that has a power supply of +/- 10 V, which one of these graphs is correct?

Comment: Either one can be correct. It depends on how the amplifier gain and bias are set up, which isn't known. So a lot of unknows must be asssumed when saying either answer is right. Do you have the exact circuit to where the signal is applied to?

Comment: It wasn't given to me, something that I don't really understand though is what does it mean power supply of +/-12V. Is it +12V or -12V, or could it be any voltage in that interval?

Comment: Elena, a supply always has two connectors, right? One of these us held at +12 V, the other at -12 V (relative to some arbitrarily defined 0 V potential) by the supply.

Comment: What are your thoughts about the two choices in front of you?

Comment: Also, even if the amplifier would be defined, it is still unclear what kind of rectangular waveform is sent to amplifier input, so unknown in is unknown out.

Comment: the one that matches the input signal frequency

Comment: @mmmm `supply always has two connectors` is kind of misleading ... what about a dual power supply? ... technically it is two power supplies, but both may required for the correct operation of the circuit ... in that case the supply has three connectors

Answer (score 1):

Neither graph is *correct* (as in: 0 points if you draw that in an exam) as the axis labeling is absent and hence we could guess, at best, that the black horizontal line is the time axis at 0 V.

Using that guess: it depends on your definition of "square wave". Does a square wave have a positive and a negative half, or does it only alternate between a positive and zero voltage?

It depends on how your material defines it, so I think you'll be able to look that up yourself and then very quickly come to a solution of your own without our help!

Answer (score -2):

The first one is correct.

Your signal ranges from 0 to 2 V and there are no reasons for the output to go below zero.

Comment: The OP has asked a homework question then made no attempt to answer. You have obliged by handing the answer over with no attempt to educate the OP or encourage them to learn. How is this answer beneficial for the OP in the long-term?

Comment: The amplifier and the input waveform to amplifier is not defined in any detail necessary to know which output is correct.